# How can I recover a git stash operation that doesn't have a tree root?

Tags: git, recovery

I had a strange problem this morning. I had a working directory and attempted to commit some changes. During the commit (I have no idea how), my system froze and required a reboot. As a result, somehow the git tree became corrupted.

Normally, this wouldn't be much of an issue, but I couldn't really do anything in the tree because there were 0-size objects. After removing them from the `.git` directory, I was able to `git stash save` my local changes. However, now when I try to `git stash pop`, I receive the following error:

```
fatal: unable to read tree 315bb2f5556d4a330abb7a1bdc26cfabf927d783
```

Basically, what it seems to be telling me is that it can't find the commit from which to generate the diff for the file in question. Ideally, I'd like to restore this stash so I can pop it and commit my work, but, barring this, is it possible to see the state of files absolutely from this stash (i.e. see the state of text files in my source directory and recreate the changes in my working directory from a "known good" state by hand).

I've tried running `git fsck`, but it complains about a series of dangling refs and doesn't actually do anything to the repo in question to fix any problem(s). I'm not quite sure what else to try, as the internals of `git` are a bit of a black box to me.

**UPDATE**:

I did now notice this in the output of `git fsck`:

```
broken link from    tree 946ebd49a429a1f9e0f48ba7af56ef680287635e
              to    tree 315bb2f5556d4a330abb7a1bdc26cfabf927d783
```

This is the only `broken link` type of message in the output, but I am not sure what it means.

Comment: First try restarting your client if you're using some sort of GIT UI, otherwise try restarting your entire computer. Believe it or not, that often fixes the problem! If not, you should be able to push the parent commit to the `origin`. From here, you should be able to `git cat-file -p` with the ID of the problematic commit, to see how much of your stash got corrupted. You can probably even just re-do the changes manually in a separate commit once you know the differences (assuming there's only a few files).

Comment: Ironically, I have rebooted many times. :) This happened as a result of maintenance needing to be done to the computer, so not only was it rebooted, but PopOs was reinstalled. I am not using a git gui, just the command line. I've restored from a file backup (not from origin) to get to this point.

Comment: I'll try using git cat-file

Comment: The really short answer is that your stash is corrupted (you already knew this) and likely not completely recoverable. There's no easy way to *partly* recover either: you'll have to delve deep into Git's internals to recover what you can.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to re-create the commit by hand from memory. I doubt this question will ever be answered successfully, since the corrupted repo is now "fixed" and the stash is gone.